# is not a member of 'std::vector<_Ty>

Tags: c++

There is a problem with this function and I can not do a compail

```
TPacketGCShopStart* p = (TPacketGCShopStart*)vecBuffer.data();
```

`Error  1   error C2039: 'data' : is not a member of 'std::vector<_Ty>' e:\source\clinet\UserInterface\PythonNetworkStreamPhaseGame.cpp 1691    UserInterface`

Comment: First of all, don't use C-style casting in C++. It's often a sign that you're doing something wrong.

Comment: Enable C++ 11...

Comment: As for your problem, which version of Visual C++ (I'm guessing) are you using? It seems that you're using a very old version, one that doesn't implement the C++11 standard where [the `data` function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data) was added.

Comment: i use 2008 So what is the solution

Comment: Upgrade if you can.  If you can't you have to use the `&vector_name[0]` hack.

Comment: how to can you help me

Comment: switch (packet_shop.subheader)
 {
  case SHOP_SUBHEADER_GC_START:
   {
    CPythonShop::Instance().Clear();

    TPacketGCShopStart* p = (TPacketGCShopStart*)vecBuffer.data();
    for (BYTE iItemIndex = 0; iItemIndex < SHOP_HOST_ITEM_MAX_NUM; ++iItemIndex)
     CPythonShop::Instance().SetItemData(iItemIndex, p->items[iItemIndex]);

#ifdef __OFFLINE_SHOP__
    PyCallClassMemberFunc(m_apoPhaseWnd[PHASE_WINDOW_GAME], "StartShop", Py_BuildValue("(iii)", p->vid, p->owner_vid, p->grid_type));
#else

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you use a version of Visual Studio and its C++ compiler that doesn't support the C++11 standard (where [the `data` function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data) was added) you have two solutions:

1. Update to a later version of Visual Studio.
2. Remember that the memory handled by `std::vector` is contiguous like for an array, and that you can then get a pointer to the first element using the same syntax: `TPacketGCShopStart* p = &vecBuffer[0]`

I rather recommend the first solution, updating the IDE, since VS2008 is neither supported nor support many of the modern C++ functionality that makes life much easier as a C++ programmer.

Comment: thanks problem this
  for (auto it = m_mapShopSign.begin(); it != m_mapShopSign.end(); ++it)

error
missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

Comment: @EMadYounis Same problem, `auto` for type deduction of variables was added with C++11.